# Is there a way to server the response to a POST request to another client?

Tags: javascript, api, websocket

I have deployed a license plate detection model in a container. It is being fed live streams(25 fps) from a CCTV. The video is split frame by frame and each second the model generates 25 outputs. I want to be able to send the 25 responses per second to the front end. Is there any way to achieve that?

The source client is sending data using POST request while the front end will probably be connected via websockets.

Comment: That's called "proxying" and it's fairly common.

Comment: Hi Paul. Can you give me some links as to where can I start with proxying?